# "one more step" or "one step further" or "one more step further"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

> 1. The analysis of intentionality needs yet to take one more step.
> 2. The analysis of intentionality needs yet to take one step further.
> 3. The analysis of intentionality needs yet to take one more step further.

I've already taken a couple of steps in analyzing intentionality. As the steps mean advancing the analysis of intentionality, I think 3 is the best choice. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"One more step further" is not particularly idiomatic. "One more step" is idiomatic as are "one step further" and "one further step."

Perhaps you want to avoid limiting yourself to just one further step. In that case, "yet one or more steps."